# how to see if a first character is present in a list(python)

Tags: python

I want to see if an element in a list has a specific character as its first one and I want to check for every element:
for example, if I have a list with 4 random strings and I want to see if the the letter a is the first character of the any string in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the list.filter functionality for it

```
>>> words = ["hello", "foo", "bar", "fred"]
>>> print(list(filter(lambda word: word.startswith("f"), words)))
['foo', 'fred']
```

Comment: how do i make it so that if the filter returns something i can give a error message

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to solve this with string method `startswith()`:

```
mylist=['this is a string', 'and so is this', 'and one more', 'here is the last']    
outlist=[x for x in mylist if x.startswith('a')]
print(outlist)
```

This is functionally equivalent to :

```
mylist=['this is a string', 'and so is this', 'and one more', 'here is the last']

outlist=[]
for x in mylist: 
    if x.startswith('a'):
        outlist.append(x)

print(outlist)
```